# accessing nth column of a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, cell, cell-array

I have a cell array with for example 3 cells, in which cells are (3,8), (3,2), (3, 30) matrices, now I want to access the nth column of whole data without converting my cell to matrix, for example, if I search for 8th column, it must be the second column of 3th cell. one way is to convert it into a matrix, but my cell is too long and it gives me out of memory when I try to convert the whole cell to the matrix. then I tried this the code below, but it doesn't work correctly. i want to know what i'm doing wrong.

any help is appreciated.

```
function [col,i,idx] = find_cellCol(cel, idx)
lgh = length(cel);
i = 1;

me = zeros(2,length(cel));
while( i <= lgh && length(cel{1,i})<=idx)

idx = idx - length(cel{1,i});
i = i+1;

end%end while

if idx == 0
col = cel{1,i-1}(:,end);
else
col = cel{1,i}(:,idx);
end
end
```

Comment: `length(x)` is the same as `max(size(x))`. You want to use `size(x,2)` to get the number of columns in an array.

Answer (score 4):

Get only the number of line of each matrix of each cell, then sum those number of line and check on wich cell you reach the 8th line.

```
%dummy data
x{1} = rand(3,8);
x{2} = rand(3,2);
x{3} = rand(3,20);

val   = 8;
csize = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),x);    %get the number of line for each cell
csum  = cumsum(csize);                % [3,6,9]
ind   = find(csum>=val,1);            % on which cell do we reach the # line
x{ind}((val-csum(ind))+csize(ind),:)  %access the right line

fprintf('Accessing the line %d of the cell %d',(val-csum(ind))+csize(ind),ind)
```

Which will return:

```
Accessing the line 2 of the cell 3
```

EDIT:

The given example mislead me since I was sure that you were trying to access a line (first dimension) and not a column (2nd dimension).

But if you want to access a column you can simply adjust the code above:

```
val   = 8;
csize = cellfun(@(x) size(x,2),x);    %get the size of the second dimension now.
csum  = cumsum(csize);                
ind   = find(csum>=val,1);            
x{ind}(:,(val-csum(ind))+csize(ind))  %access the right column
```

Comment: Nice, except the OP wants to get *columns*, not rows. This means you should use `size(x,2)` instead of `size(x,1)`, and fix the indexing later on.

Comment: thanks a lot, guys – CrisLuengo, – obchardon.
but when I'm trying to find the first column it gives me: 

Accessing the column 1 of the cell -7Accessing column 1 of the cell 2;

and also "ind" has two values!

Comment: @AZiZASaber looks like you have modified the code above. Use `find(condition,1)` where 1 indicate that `find` must return only the first occurence.